# How to fix ".service: Start request repeated too quickly." on custom service?

Tags: debian, systemd, services, start-stop-daemon

I'm learning how to create services with systemd. I get this error:

```
.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
```

I can't start the service any more; it was working yesterday. What am I doing wrong?

```
(root@Kundrum)-(11:03:19)-(~)
$nano /lib/systemd/system/swatchWATCH.service
 1 [Unit]
 2 Description=Monitor Logfiles and send Mail reports
 3 After=syslog.target network.target
 4
 5 [Service]
 6 Type=simple
 7 ExecStart=/usr/bin/swatch --config-file=/home/kristjan/.swatchrc --input-record-separator="\n \n " --tail-file=/var/log/snort/alert --daemon
 8 Restart=on-failure
 9 StartLimitInterval=3
10 StartLimitBurst=100
11
12 [Install]
13 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`StartLimitInterval` and `StartLimitBurst` I added after trying to fix it.

My system is Debian 9.8 Stretch all updates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, if this is a custom service, it belongs in `/etc/systemd/system`. `/lib/systemd` is intended for package-provided files.

Second, the service is likely crashing and systemd is attempted to restart it repeatedly, so you need to figure out why it's crashing. Check the service logs with:

```
journalctl -e -u swatchWATCH
```

It's possible there will be some extra detail in the main journal:

```
journalctl -e
```

Finally, check to see it runs directly on the CLI ok:

/usr/bin/swatch --config-file=/home/kristjan/.swatchrc --input-record-separator="\n \n " --tail-file=/var/log/snort/alert --daemon

I see you are using a `--daemon` option. That's often a mistake with systemd. Systemd daemonizes for you. Try removing this option.

If all else fails, review what changed since yesterday when it was working.

Comment: Note that `journalctl -u UNIT` does not reliably display the dying messages of a unit, because there's no way to determine the origin cgroup of a message if the origin process is already dead.

Comment: grepping the journalctl -e fixed my problem. I found a line of code which was reliant on another service (MQTT broker) already being started. So, it appeared to work from the the commandline, but it would never start after a reboot.

Answer (score 9):

The quick solution to "systemd[1]: SERVICE: Start request repeated too quickly" is

```
systemctl reset-failed SERVICE
systemctl start SERVICE
systemctl status SERVICE
```

Relevant quote from ***man systemctl***:

> reset-failed [PATTERN...]
>
> ... the start rate limit counter is reset to zero.
> Thus, if a unit's start limit (as configured with
> `StartLimitIntervalSec=/StartLimitBurst=`) is
> hit and the unit refuses to be started again, use
> this command to make it startable again."

Comment: Can you explain what `reset-failed` does?

Comment: @annahri `man systemctl`: "the start rate limit counter is reset to zero". "if a unit's start limit (as configured with StartLimitIntervalSec=/StartLimitBurst=) is hit and the unit refuses to be started again, use this command to make it startable again."

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error message was somewhat misleading. The reason for the failure resulted from a copy between machines. The line

```
User=my_user
```

in my service configuration file `/etc/systemd/system/infinite_script.service` was the culprit.

The new machine did not know of this user. Changing to `User=root` solved this problem.